# AWS codecommit vulnerability scanning

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

i am wondering if automatic "code scanning" is available in AWS's codecommit or not, for any vulnerabilities or errors.(sensitive data like username, password, access-key, etc.)

basically it will analyze repository's code after each check-in to find the security vulnerabilities and show the report or alert.

Thanks

Found no info in aws codecommit documentation.

Comment: Not natively. You'll need something like a lambda https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/discovering-sensitive-data-in-aws-codecommit-with-aws-lambda-2/

Comment: many thanks @Paolo for sharing, i was looking for inbuilt solution like we have in GitHub. this is also quite interesting, we could give a try.